# Tampermonkey replacing words with images

Tags: tampermonkey

This code in Tampermonkey replaces the word "Goals" with "Goals", but adds an image of a goal beside it.  How can I modify this statement so it replaces the letter "G" when it's only a letter "G", and not with words like "Greenville"?

E: Specifically on a page like this:
http://oua.ca/sports/mice/2016-17/teams/ryerson?view=lineup

So the header G (goals) A (assists) has an icon beside them.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Goals/g,'<img src="##" height="20"> GOALS');
})();
```

Comment: `/\bG\b/g` ? Anyway, replacing the entire html breaks event listeners, the correct approach is to iterate text nodes via document.createTreeWalker or document.evaluate

Comment: So what would that code look like?

Comment: It works, but not in the top header like I needed. Appreciated though!

Comment: `Inspect` the element and you'll see it's lowercase `g` internally so the regex should be `/\bg\b/g` or case-insensitive `/\bg\b/gi`

Comment: Where do I put the document.createTreeWalker etc? Can you write it out in full so I can see it all? Thanks!

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Ao73o

Comment: There are many existing examples. Right now I can't post a full answer.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! I'll keep trying.  Really not good with Java.  Just trying to do this one thing for our hockey team.

Comment: userscripts use javascript, not java... there is a difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use CSS to modify the appearance.

The advantage is that you can do it before the page is shown (@run-at: document-start) so your modifications will appear without any delay. This can be done with [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) even without a userscript.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         oua logos in header
// @match        http://oua.ca/sports/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle(`
    th a[href*="?sort=g&"] {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background: url(http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-g-icon-png-20.png);
        display: inline-block;
        color: transparent!important;
        background-size: 16px;
        margin-left: -32px;
    }
    th a[href*="?sort=g&"]:after {
        content: "GOALS";
        color: white;
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
`);
```

---

#### Use MutationObserver to modify the element before it's shown.

An example using [setMutationHandler](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/12228-setmutationhandler) wrapper:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         oua logos in header
// @match        http://oua.ca/sports/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @require      https://greasyfork.org/scripts/12228/code/setMutationHandler.js
// ==/UserScript==

iconizeHeader(document.querySelectorAll('th a'));
setMutationHandler(document, 'th a', iconizeHeader);

function iconizeHeader(elements) {
    for (var i = 0, e; (e = elements[i++]); ) {
        var newImage, newText;
        switch (e.textContent) {
            case 'g':
                newImage = 'http://..................';
                newText = 'GOALS';
                break;
            case 'pts':
                newImage = 'http://............';
                newText = 'POINTS';
                break;
            default:
                continue;
        }
        e.textContent = newText;
        e.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',
                             '<img src="' + newImage + '" width=16 height=16>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.  Been stumped on this for months!

Comment: @DaveWhiffen, if this answer works for you, [tick the checkmark next to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).